# How to return specific word bfore the matched expression

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

As part of a larger code I have to get specific field from the line below.

```
user    25999  0.0  0.7 678772 259772 ?       Ssl  Nov05  11:54 fwd
```

I have a file full of data which have similar lines. I need the value before ? returned from all the lines. I am stuck. Tried `awk -F '?' '{print $1}' | awk '{print $NF}' test1.txt`, which spat out garbage. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You say you want to get "specific field", but without explaining which field.

Comment: By default, fields are delimited by whitespaces in awk. No need to define a new field delimiter, you only have to display the 6th field.

Comment: Given that input all you need is `awk '{print $6}'`. If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input and expected output demonstrating why that's not adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this as the test file:

```
$ cat file
user    25999  0.0  0.7 678772 259772 ?       Ssl  Nov05  11:54 fwd
```

To get the value before the `?`, try:

```
$ awk '{sub(/?.*/, ""); print $NF}' file
259772
```

The command `sub(/?.*/, "")` eliminates all text from `?` to the end of the line.  After this is done, the last field on the newly revised line, `$NF`, is the one you want.

#### Discussion

This doesn't work:

```
$ awk -F '?' '{print $1}' | awk '{print $NF}' file
fwd
```

What happens above is that `awk '{print $NF}' file` reads from `file` and prints out the last field on the line.  The stdin from `awk -F '?' '{print $1}'` is ignored.

By placing the name of the file in the first command, though, we can achieve what you want:

```
$ awk -F '?' '{print $1}' file | awk '{print $NF}' 
259772
```

#### Answer for Second Version of Question

Let's take this test file:

```
$ cat file
user1    25999  0.0  0.7 678772  259772 ?       Ssl  Nov05  11:54 fwd
user2    25999  0.0  0.7 678772 1500000 ?       Ssl  Nov05  11:54 fwd
user3    25999  0.0  0.7 678772  259772 ?       Ssl  Nov05  11:54 fwd
```

As per your comments, to print the number before `?` only if it is >=1500000 and to print the first field from the previous line:

```
$ awk '{sub(/?.*/, "")} $NF>=1500000{print last,$NF} {last=$1}' file
user1 1500000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have gnu grep which supports Perl Regex you can use something like this :

```
$ grep -Po '.* \K\w+ (?=[?])' file
```

Testing:

```
$ echo "$a"
user    25999  0.0  0.7 678772 259772 ?       Ssl  Nov05  11:54 fwd
$ echo "$a" |grep -Po '.* \K\w+ (?=[?])'
259772
```

`\K` in Perl Regex means "forget previous matches"
`?=` in Perl Regex is a lookahead assertion
`[?]` is a literal ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with 
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="?" && $(i-1)>=1500000) print $(i-1)}' filename.txt
It prints all lines in my file with value before '?' > 1500000. I also need first word of the previous line along with this number. Thi code will not work as it is traversing each word one line at a time.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Nowhere in your original question do you mention the requirement for >1500000 or for saving the "first word of the previous line".  It is bad form to change a question so dramatically after answers have been posted.  Nevertheless, I updated my answer to meet these new requirements.